# Why is image segmentation using AI longer at each iteration of a loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization, image-segmentation

I have an annoying problem when using a U-NET neural network to perform image segmentation on a batch of images. I first ask the user, through a tkinter GUI, to select the file where the images are stored. Then i go through all the image paths in a loop. In the loop, I first load the image, then process it using methods of the class. Finally i save the resulting image and I continue the loop. However, at each iteration, I observe that the time it takes for segmentation is longer and longer. I first thought it was a problem of memory management, so I took care to delete all intermediate variables, but the problem persists. Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong ? Here is my code

```py
class scratch_test_analyzer:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.model = load_model(r"E:\Elise\Scratch test\C02\test_model3_wpaddinng\segmentation_unet_v3_epochs30_padding.h5")
        self.root = root
        root.title("Scratch test analyzer")

        self.interface()
    
    def interface(self):
        get_folder_button = tk.Button(self.root,text="Choisir le dossier",command=self.get_folder)
        get_folder_button.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def get_folder(self):
        self.folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        #set a global variable to save the folder path
        global folder_path
        folder_path = self.folder_path
        file_list = os.listdir(self.folder_path)
        self.tif_files = []
        for file_name in file_list:
            if file_name.endswith('.TIF'):
                self.tif_files.append(file_name)

        filenames_data = [self.file_name_interpreter(filename) for filename in self.tif_files]

        self.filename_df = pd.DataFrame(filenames_data)

        experiment_names = np.array(self.filename_df['experiment_name'].unique()).tolist()
        plate_names = np.array(self.filename_df['plate_name'].unique()).tolist()
        timepoints = np.array(self.filename_df['timepoint'].unique()).tolist()
        column_identifiers = np.array(self.filename_df['column_identifier'].unique()).tolist()
        row_numbers = np.array(self.filename_df['row_number'].unique()).tolist()
        fluorescence_channels = np.array(self.filename_df['fluorescence_channel'].unique()).tolist()

        from_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="Choix de t0: ")
        from_label.grid(row=1,column=4)

        to_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="Choix de tfin: ")
        to_label.grid(row=1,column=5)

        first_column_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="Choix de la première colonne: ")
        first_column_label.grid(row=1,column=7)

        last_column_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="Choix de la dernière colonne: ")
        last_column_label.grid(row=1,column=8)

        first_row_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="Choix de la première ligne: ")
        first_row_label.grid(row=1,column=9)

        last_row_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="Choix de la dernière ligne: ")
        last_row_label.grid(row=1,column=10)

        self.experiment_names_cb = Combobox(self.root,values=experiment_names)
        self.experiment_names_cb.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.underscore_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="_")
        self.underscore_label.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.plate_names_cb = Combobox(self.root,values=plate_names)
        self.plate_names_cb.grid(row=2,column=2)

        next_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="_p")
        next_label.grid(row=2,column=3)

        self.first_timestep_cb = Combobox(self.root,values=timepoints)
        self.first_timestep_cb.grid(row=2,column=4)

        self.last_timestep_cb = Combobox(self.root,values=timepoints)
        self.last_timestep_cb.grid(row=2,column=5)

        label3 = tk.Label(self.root,text="_0_")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=6)

        self.column_identifiers_cb_begin = Combobox(self.root,values=column_identifiers)
        self.column_identifiers_cb_begin.grid(row=2,column=7)

        self.column_identifiers_cb_end = Combobox(self.root,values=column_identifiers)
        self.column_identifiers_cb_end.grid(row=2,column=8)

        self.first_row_number_cb = Combobox(self.root,values=row_numbers)
        self.first_row_number_cb.grid(row=2,column=9)

        self.last_row_number_cb = Combobox(self.root,values=row_numbers)
        self.last_row_number_cb.grid(row=2,column=10)

        self.fluorescence_channels_cb = Combobox(self.root,values=fluorescence_channels)
        self.fluorescence_channels_cb.grid(row=2,column=11)

        validate_button = tk.Button(self.root,text="Valider",command=self.validate)
        validate_button.grid(row=2,column=12)

    def validate(self):
        # Get the values from the comboboxes
        self.experiment_name = self.experiment_names_cb.get()
        self.plate_name = self.plate_names_cb.get()
        self.first_timepoint = self.first_timestep_cb.get()
        self.last_timepoint = self.last_timestep_cb.get()
        self.column_identifier_begin = self.column_identifiers_cb_begin.get()
        self.column_identifier_end = self.column_identifiers_cb_end.get()
        self.row_number_begin = self.first_row_number_cb.get()
        self.row_number_end = self.last_row_number_cb.get()
        self.fluorescence_channel = self.fluorescence_channels_cb.get()

        self.initiate_analysis()

    def initiate_analysis(self):
        # subset the dataframe to only include the files with selected properties
        self.subset_df = self.filename_df[
                (self.filename_df['experiment_name'] == self.experiment_name) &
                (self.filename_df['plate_name'] == self.plate_name) &
                (self.filename_df['timepoint'] >= self.first_timepoint) &
                (self.filename_df['timepoint'] <= self.last_timepoint) &
                (self.filename_df['column_identifier'] >= self.column_identifier_begin) &
                (self.filename_df['column_identifier'] <= self.column_identifier_end) &
                (self.filename_df['row_number'] >= self.row_number_begin) &
                (self.filename_df['row_number'] <= self.row_number_end) &
                (self.filename_df['fluorescence_channel'] == self.fluorescence_channel)
            ]
        
        #get number of rows in the dataframe
        nb_rows = len(self.subset_df)

        #add a progress bar to show the progress of the analysis
        self.progress_bar = tk.ttk.Progressbar(self.root,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,length=nb_rows,mode='determinate',maximum=nb_rows)
        self.progress_bar.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=13)

        #add a label to show the progress of the analysis
        self.progress_label = tk.Label(self.root,text="0%")
        self.progress_label.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=13)
        
        #pop a filedialog to ask the user to enter a number corresponding to the time point of the scratch
        #timestep = simpledialog.askinteger("Pas de temps", "Quel est le pas de temps entre chaque image (en heures)?",parent=self.root)

        
        #iterate over the rows of the dataframe
        for row in self.subset_df.itertuples():
            start_time = time.time()
            file_name = f"{row.experiment_name}_{row.plate_name}_p{row.timepoint}_0_{row.column_identifier}{row.row_number}{row.fluorescence_channel}.TIF"
            file_path = os.path.join(self.folder_path,file_name)
            image = imread(file_path)
            mask = self.predict_mask(image)
            brand_new_image = image[:,:,1]
            #add confluence to the dataframe
            self.save_mask(mask,row.experiment_name,row.plate_name,row.timepoint,row.column_identifier,row.row_number,row.fluorescence_channel,"_mask")
            result_image = brand_new_image.copy()
            edges = canny(mask, sigma=2)
            binary_edges = np.zeros_like(result_image)
            binary_edges[edges] = 255
            # Create an empty color image
            color_image_green = np.zeros((result_image.shape[0], result_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            color_image_red = np.zeros((result_image.shape[0], result_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            color_image = np.zeros((result_image.shape[0], result_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            # Set the red channel to the grayscale image
            color_image_red[:, :, 0] = binary_edges
            # Set the green channel to the grayscale image
            color_image_green[:, :, 1] = result_image
            color_image = color_image_green + color_image_red
            self.save_mask(color_image,row.experiment_name,row.plate_name,row.timepoint,row.column_identifier,row.row_number,row.fluorescence_channel,"_merge")

            del file_name
            del file_path
            del image
            del mask
            del brand_new_image
            del result_image
            del edges
            del binary_edges
            del color_image_green
            del color_image_red
            del color_image

            self.progress_bar['value'] += 1
            self.progress_bar.update()
            self.progress_label['text'] = f"{round(self.progress_bar['value']/nb_rows*100)}%"
            self.progress_label.update()

            end_time = time.time()
            print(f"Elapsed time : {end_time-start_time}")
        self.root.destroy()


    def save_mask(self,mask,experiment_name,plate_name,first_timepoint,column_identifier,row_number_begin,fluorescence_channel,suffix):
        suffix = suffix
        # Create a new folder for the masks if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.folder_path, f'masks_{column_identifier}{row_number_begin}')):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(self.folder_path, f'masks_{column_identifier}{row_number_begin}'))

        # Save the mask
        mask_filename = f"mask_{experiment_name}_{plate_name}_p{first_timepoint}_0_{column_identifier}{row_number_begin}{fluorescence_channel}{suffix}.jpg"
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.folder_path, f'masks_{column_identifier}{row_number_begin}', mask_filename)
        plt.imsave(mask_path, mask, cmap='gray')

        del suffix
        del mask_filename
        del mask_path

    def predict_mask(self,image):
        brand_new_image = image[:,:,1]
        desired_size = 258
        patch_size = (256, 256)
        patches = view_as_blocks(brand_new_image, patch_size)
        predicted_masks = np.zeros_like(brand_new_image,dtype=np.float32)
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(patches.shape[0]):
            for j in range(patches.shape[1]):
                patch = patches[i, j]
                #plt.imshow(patch)
                #plt.show()
                
                # Ensure the patch has the correct shape (256x256)
                if patch.shape == patch_size:
                    pad_row_top = (desired_size - patch.shape[0]) // 2
                    pad_row_bottom = desired_size - patch.shape[0] - pad_row_top
                    pad_col_left = (desired_size - patch.shape[1]) // 2
                    pad_col_right = desired_size - patch.shape[1] - pad_col_left
                    
                    patch = np.pad(patch, ((pad_row_top, pad_row_bottom), (pad_col_left, pad_col_right)), mode='constant', constant_values=255)

                    # Normalize the patch and add a batch dimension
                    patch = patch / 255
                    patch = np.expand_dims(patch, axis=(0, -1))
                    
                    # Predict the mask for the patch
                    predicted_patch = self.model.predict(patch, verbose=0)
                    
                    # Remove padding
                    predicted_patch = predicted_patch[0, 1:257, 1:257, 0]
                    
                    # Update the predicted_masks with the predicted patch
                    predicted_masks[i * patch_size[0]: (i + 1) * patch_size[0],
                                    j * patch_size[1]: (j + 1) * patch_size[1]] = predicted_patch
        
        thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(predicted_masks, classes=2)
        thresh_mask_otsu = predicted_masks > thresholds[0]
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Elapsed time mask prediction : {end_time-start_time}")
        del image
        del start_time
        del end_time
        del pad_row_top
        del pad_row_bottom
        del pad_col_left
        del pad_col_right
        del patch
        del predicted_patch
        del brand_new_image
        del desired_size
        del patch_size
        del patches
        del predicted_masks
        del thresholds

        return thresh_mask_otsu

    def file_name_interpreter(self,filename):
        # Split the filename into parts based on underscores
        parts = filename.split('_')

        experiment_name = parts[0]
        plate_name = f"{parts[1]}_{parts[2]}"  

        # Extract the timepoint (remove 'p' from the start)
        timepoint = parts[3][1:]

        # Extract the column identifier
        column_identifier = parts[5][0]

        # Extract the row number (remove any non-digit characters)
        row_number = parts[5][1:3]

        fluorescence_channel = parts[5][3:-4]  # Remove 'f' and '.TIF'

        del parts

        return {
            'experiment_name': experiment_name,
            'plate_name': plate_name,
            'timepoint': timepoint,
            'column_identifier': column_identifier,
            'row_number': row_number,
            'fluorescence_channel': fluorescence_channel
        }
```

Here is what is returned in the console at the beginning :
<tifffile.TiffFile 'ST035_Plate_D_p16_0_B03f00d1.TIF'> OME series cannot handle discontiguous storage ((1536, 2048, 3) != (2, 1536, 2048))
Elapsed time mask prediction : 5.125787734985352
Elapsed time : 5.886773586273193

and mid-execution :
<tifffile.TiffFile 'ST035_Plate_D_p19_0_D03f00d1.TIF'> OME series cannot handle discontiguous storage ((1536, 2048, 3) != (2, 1536, 2048))
Elapsed time mask prediction : 12.35139799118042
Elapsed time : 13.318671464920044

--> Edit : I added a block at the end of initiate_analysis(), where I clear the keras session and reload the model if overall analysis time exceeds a threshold (7 s). It worked for an overnight execcution, prediction time was stabilized arround 5-6 seconds. Still looking for a more "elegant" solution though !

```py
        for row in self.subset_df.itertuples():
            start_time = time.time()
            file_name = f"{row.experiment_name}_{row.plate_name}_p{row.timepoint}_0_{row.column_identifier}{row.row_number}{row.fluorescence_channel}.TIF"
            file_path = os.path.join(self.folder_path,file_name)
            image = imread(file_path)
            mask = self.predict_mask(image)
            brand_new_image = image[:,:,1]
            #add confluence to the dataframe
            self.save_mask(mask,row.experiment_name,row.plate_name,row.timepoint,row.column_identifier,row.row_number,row.fluorescence_channel,"_mask")
            result_image = brand_new_image.copy()
            edges = canny(mask, sigma=2)
            binary_edges = np.zeros_like(result_image)
            binary_edges[edges] = 255
            # Create an empty color image
            color_image_green = np.zeros((result_image.shape[0], result_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            color_image_red = np.zeros((result_image.shape[0], result_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            color_image = np.zeros((result_image.shape[0], result_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            # Set the red channel to the grayscale image
            color_image_red[:, :, 0] = binary_edges
            # Set the green channel to the grayscale image
            color_image_green[:, :, 1] = result_image
            color_image = color_image_green + color_image_red
            self.save_mask(color_image,row.experiment_name,row.plate_name,row.timepoint,row.column_identifier,row.row_number,row.fluorescence_channel,"_merge")

            del file_name
            del file_path
            del image
            del mask
            del brand_new_image
            del result_image
            del edges
            del binary_edges
            del color_image_green
            del color_image_red
            del color_image

            self.progress_bar['value'] += 1
            self.progress_bar.update()
            self.progress_label['text'] = f"{round(self.progress_bar['value']/nb_rows*100)}%"
            self.progress_label.update()

            end_time = time.time()
            print(f"Elapsed time : {end_time-start_time}")
            if end_time-start_time>7:
                #delete self.model
                K.clear_session()
                self.model = load_model(r"E:\Elise\Scratch test\C02\test_model3_wpaddinng\segmentation_unet_v3_epochs30_padding.h5")
        self.root.destroy()
```

Comment: Have you tried timing just the predict statement?

Comment: Yes, with verbose=1 the predict function returns the prediction time. It goes forever higher. However I think I found a technic, maybe not very elegent, that worked for a run overnight, stabilizing the prediction time to arround 6 seconds. I added a block at the end of initiate_analysis(), that clears the keras session when prediction time (well here it is overall analysis time) goes higher than a threshold. It seems that keras accumulates data when using a model multiple times, clearing the session and reloading the model seeùs to be the solution here. I'll post an answer with updated code.

Comment: You could profile the `predict_mask` method to find out what line(s) are getting slower. There is a lot going on in that method, so one timing of the whole method is too broad. Is the amount of patches to loop over the same for every image?

Comment: Also, for the warning you can look at this line: https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/35c19b7c6c8b85aa09e490520677b5a2a31c14e4/tifffile/tifffile.py#L5729. Maybe it helps, I don't know enough how TIFF works.